# SSL_Connect() issue using Indy10 library in Delphi

Tags: openssl, indy10

I am using RAD Studio 10.4.

I am trying to implement TLS (Transport layer Security) through Indy10 in my application, and am facing issues in the `ssl_connect()` function, as it returns 0.  I am using some set of APIs from `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas` but nothing works for me.

I have downloaded OpenSSL 1.0.2 from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/, which is said to be compatible with Indy10.

Can anybody suggest how `ssl_connect()` can work successfully? Or, is there some other link from where I can get the latest Indy10 and OpenSSL libraries?

Also, these OpenSSL libraries are taken from path `c:\system32` for a 64bit application? I have copied the OpenSSL DLLs under this path.

Below is a small piece of code for my `ssl_connect()` implementation:

```pascal
function TIPSTcpLink.tls_handshake(ssl:PSSL; fd:Integer): Integer;
var
  rv ,err :integer;
  msg : PAnsiChar;
begin
  if (SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd) <= 0) then begin
    TR_PRINT('SSL_set_fd', -1 ,ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), ''));     //recheck thsi print
  end;
    
  ERR_clear_error();
  rv := SSL_connect(ssl);
  TR_Print('value of rv is >>',-1,IntToStr(rv));
  err := SSL_get_error(ssl,rv);
  case err of
    SSL_ERROR_SSL:
      print('Error :: SSL_ERROR_SSL:');
    SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
      print('Error :: SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ');
  end;
  if (rv <= 0) then begin
    Print('SSL_connect Error');
  end;
  Result := rv;
end;
```

Comment: You say `SSL_connect()` is returning 0, but you do not say what `SSL_get_error()` is returning to explain WHY `SSL_connect()` failed. But if you are using Indy anyway, then why are you using the OpenSSL API manually at all instead of letting Indy handle the connection and TLS for you? Also, you should NOT be putting 3rd party DLLs into Windows' installation folder. Put the DLLs in your app's folder instead, or any other folder that your app owns. If needed, you can use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function to tell Indy where to load the DLLs from.

Comment: And just FYI, the https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ archive is dead, use Indy's GitHub repo from now on. See this blog article on Indy's website: [OpenSSL binaries moved to GitHub](https://www.indyproject.org/2020/06/16/openssl-binaries-moved-to-github/)

Comment: Note the return from `SSL_get_error` after error in 'blocking' code like this is always `SSL_ERROR_SSL` or `SSL_ERROR_SYCALL` (not `SSL_WANT_anything`) and in the former case you should ALSO look at `ERR_get_error` (preferably looping until 0) or in the latter case the _Windows_ error `GetLastError` (or Unix `errno`) @RemyLebeau

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, and I am landing into SSL_ERROR_SSL  error. One more help which particular unit (.pas) from Indy10 can be used for OPENSSL implementation as earlier mentioned I am using IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas which imports OPENSSL APIs from the libraries like ssleay32.dll etc.